# Alternative to s4.recentchanges class

Tags: sharepoint-server

I want to use css to hide the "Recent" section but unfortunately I couldn't find the alternative to `s4.recentchanges` class for SharePoint 2013

I don't want to hide the entire quick launch using `#sideNavBox` or use jQuery to hide it.

I want to hide only "Recent" section

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The class you're looking for is `.additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow` which is the same on the *Recent* title and all contained items.

Comment: Hi Benny, thanks for your answer. I created a text file with the code .additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow { display: none; } embedded within style tag. I uploaded that in XSL Stylesheets and then referenced the location to alternate CSS location under Master page. But still it 's not working. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Do you see the embedded style in the source code when you reload the page? If not, you could use a link reference in your master page to a custom css-file.

Comment: I didn't use the content editor/ script editor to hide it. I intend to use the code in alternate CSS location. I can't edit the master page option

Comment: I mean the Alternate CSS URL settings under Site settings-> Look and feel-> Master Page

Comment: @ChandraShekhar That should work just as well. But if you don't see it in the source something may not be right. As a test, you could add the important flag to your css rule `display:none !important;`

Comment: Hi, this is the code that I'm using saving it in text file <style type="text/css">
#additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow { display: none !important; }
</style>

Comment: @ChandraShekhar You're referencing an ID (#) instead of the class (.). Edit and try again.

Comment: I'm storing that file in XSL Style sheet library and then using the text file link in alternate CSS URL location. Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I'm using (.) instead of (#) it's the same issue

Comment: @ChandraShekhar I'm really running out of ideas. can you change anything else on the page? set background color from the same file your editing now?

Comment: I have also used the code in content editor web part on the home page. Even then its not working. Please suggest

Comment: Any ideas anyone?